# mysqli_query no longer inserting data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here's the quick story, i am a beginner at MYSQL(i) coding, so please excuse noobish errors, except this system worked until i had 4-5 friends attempt to input data at one time, in the end it ended with the database not accept further inputs **BUT** it allows the usage of my removal code, where it will remove certain data from a table.

```
<?php
require ("../config/mysql.php");
if (isset($_POST['unit']) && is_numeric($_POST['unit']))
{
    $unit = $_POST['unit']; 
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $vehicle = $_POST['vehicle']; 
    $status = $_POST['status'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`unit`, `name`, `vehicle`,`status`) VALUES ('$unit', '$name', '$vehicle', '$status');";
    mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
else
{ 
    echo "<h2>ERROR: YOU GINGER'D IT</h2>";
    echo "<h2>YOU PUT A LETTER IN THE UNIT SLOT, GOOD JOB!</h2>";
}
?>
```

Ignore the last two echo's as it's a joke that we have between our friends.

Please note, that it works fine with exactly **ONE** person using it.

Encase you're wondering, here's my removal code:

```
<?php
require ("../config/mysql.php");
if (isset($_POST['unit']) && is_numeric($_POST['unit']))
{
    $unit = $_POST['unit'];
    $query = "DELETE from `users` WHERE unit = $unit";
    mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
else
{ 
    echo "<h2>ERROR: YOU GINGER'D IT</h2>";
    echo "<h2>YOU PUT A LETTER IN THE UNIT SLOT, GOOD JOB!</h2>"; 
}
?>
```

This code works fine, no errors. I attempted to use someone's code to show any errors, except it didn't work for me, so i am asking StackOverFlow for some assistance.

I have no idea what could be causing this error, i have searched up and down the ends of the internet for answers.

Thank You.

**EDIT**

Here is my table including current data.

```html
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Mar 21, 2016 at 05:51 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.10-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.0.4

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `cad`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `unit` text NOT NULL,
  `vehicle` text NOT NULL,
  `status` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `unit`, `vehicle`, `status`) VALUES
(0, 'Ginger', '2', 'GMC Ambulance', 'ON DUTY'),
(1, 'Mac Mcfly', '1', 'Chevy Tahoe', 'OFF DUTY');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Yeah, why are you including code snippets for PHP codes? You are aware that it only accept JS, and HTML, right?

Comment: can you please post your table structure? I guess there will be a unique index!

Comment: Ahhhh, the injection vulnerabilities, man! The injection vulnerabilities!

Comment: Wait.....What?.... Can you explain how i may switch over to JS / HTML usage? I have almost always used PHP for other projects and they worked fine. So i am confused.

Comment: can you check result of print_r($_POST) ?

Comment: @Dhruv Yes, one moment.

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: Have you ever considered testing the status of the `mysqli_query($conn, $query);` statement and if it fails outputting `mysqli_error ($link);` Its been known to help, even the day walkers

Comment: Ahh 'ello Ralph` Great mind think alike! @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Ahoy Smokey!* si signore @RiggsFolly

Comment: run once, insert one person right?

Comment: `echo "<h2>ERROR: YOU GINGER'D IT</h2>";` doesn't help you btw.

Comment: @Dhruv 
3 
Cole 
GMC Ambulance 
ON DUTY

Comment: @AndrewWelch Yes, it's supposed to, it did before. Inserted one table and then just stopped doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the code, it's the database. You obviously corrupted the database by violating the primary key. Try doing a select * on the table where your primary key is having count greater then 1. This happens when you don't have validation checks before inserting into the database.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try this.

**EDIT**:
Ok, so i don't fully understand, do you want me to "select" the primary key and make the value greater than 1 or..?

Comment: That `id` shoudl really be an `auto increment`

Comment: @AAlex Moura right
There is entry with 0 for primary key.

Comment: Agreed! We don't know what the author's dB architecture looks like. From my experience this looks like a PK violation.

Comment: @RiggsFolly How would i go about fixing the primary key to auto increment?

Comment: Use phpMyAdmin and set the column to `AI`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you, i will try this and report back.

Comment: I think best thing to do is delete the 4 records that your mates entered. Go back to you PHP add some validation go to your database make sure your primary key is Auto incremental. I don't know what the architecture of your app looks like.  So I can't advise you further. This would be your best bet moving forward.